# In Towers of Hanoi Algorithm, what is the auxiliary?

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

For example, in the following Tower of Hanoi algorithm:

```
input   Number of disk   
output  Print: disk moved successfully  
complexity  O(n).  

Tower(n , beg , aux , end)  
1.  If (n=1) then   
Beg = end;  
Return;  
2.  Call Tower(n-1 , beg ,end , aug );  
3.  Call Tower (1 ,beg ,aux ,end );  
4.  Call Tower (n-1,aux ,beg ,end);
```

What is the auxiliary suppose to represent?

Comment: Aux is the third stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three spindles in the Towers of Hanoi problem: a start spindle (where the tower begins), an end spindle (where the tower should end up), and an auxiliary spindle (the other of the three).  The auxiliary spindle is used as temporary storage space to move disks and towers in the process of getting the overall tower from the start spindle to the end spindle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! So if my problem contains Aux1, Aux2, does that mean that there are 4 spindles total?

Comment: @stevendao- Without any more context I can't say for sure.  If they're provided as parameters, my suspicion would be that yes, there are four spindles.  That said, this is probably documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If there were only two pegs, it would be impossible to move more than one disk.  To move a group containing more than one disk from e.g. peg 1 to peg 2, it is necessary to move the all but the bottom disk to a peg that is neither the origin nor destination of the group.  That other peg is referred to as the "auxiliary".  Some representations of the algorithms explicitly specify the auxiliary peg (in which case it won't matter whether the pegs are numbered 0-1-2, 1-2-3, or 11-47-93), while others require that the three pegs have three particular numbers (e.g. 0-1-2), and assume that whichever value isn't given will be the auxiliary (e.g. by computing (aux = 3-src-dest)).

Incidentally, the 3-peg version of the puzzle is used so commonly as an example it's almost a shame that no effort is made to explore variations with more pegs.  Such variations were explored in puzzle books over 100 years ago, but I've not seen any modern textbooks mention them even though I would consider them much more interesting.